# How to write proportionality in a Stan model?

Tags: bayesian, stan, rstan

I am having difficulties in writing the following equation into a Stan model.

$$
y_i = \mu(x_i) + \epsilon_i
\\ \epsilon_i \sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)
\\ \mu(x_i) = a + b x_i
\\ p(a) = p(b) \propto 1
\\ \sigma^2 \sim Inv-Gamma(0.001, 0.001)
$$

Everything else is pretty much simple and clear, but how I should interpret the line of $p(a) = p(b) \propto 1$? I assume this has to be in `transformed parameters` block, but I can't seem to find any online resources that would show good examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$$
p(a) \propto 1
$$

Says that the distribution of $a$ is proportional to constant, it’s an [improper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability)  distribution (not integrates to one). In Stan this corresponds to not specifying any prior, so unbounded uniform distribution is assumed. Using such priors are [generally not recommended](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations) and can lead to tricky results.

Comment: Thanks, this makes some sense to me. I'm still a bit lost how one would write this whole thing as a Stan model tho, so if you have any pointers about that I would be glad for the help.

Comment: @John Stan has really great [user guide](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_28/stan-users-guide/index.html) and [documentation](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/), it's the best place to start.